# VBA combobox style

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have an Excel small interface. I changed a combobox style  from **fmStyleDropDownCombo** to **fmStyleDropDownList** (I did this by - right click - Properties - Style).
Now, I get an error:

> "Could not set the Text property. Invalid property value"

on this line in VBA:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbSX.Text = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(9, 10)
```

This worked perfectly before I changed styles as described above (the change of style made the component uneditable manually). Any suggestion on how the code should be readjusted to this new style? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Text` to `Value`

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbSX.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(9, 10)
```

Comment: Thank you Doug, that worked! I wonder why combobox style is associated with .Text and list with .Value?? Also, .Text worked ok with empty cells, for .Value I had to do this: Worksheets("Sheet1").cmbSX.Value = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(9, 10) & "" so that errors wouldn't be thrown in case of empty cells.

Comment: I tried to figure out why that works when I posted the answer, but web searches don't reveal much. In my experience the difference between `Text` and `Value` is critical with multi-column comboboboxes, but that doesn't apply here. Anyways, glad it worked.