# How to use search and update buttons on a locked worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have entered code for adding data to a locked worksheet, but the search and update commands do not work when trying to change data using the userform.

I have managed to find how to add data but not how to make it work for search and update

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheet1.Protect Password:="xyz", UserInterfaceOnly:=True
End Sub

Private Sub cmdAdd_Click()
'to check the last filled row
lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(lastrow + 1, 1).Value = txtInvoiceNumber.Text


Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
txtInvoiceNumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1)
txtInvoiceDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)


Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
Cells(currentrow, 1) = txtInvoiceNumber.Text
Cells(currentrow, 3) = txtInvoiceDate.Text
```

I would like to know the code so that the search/find and update buttons also update the data while the worksheet is locked.
Thanks

The Error
[image]

The Debug
[image]

The full code

```
Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
Dim totalrow As Long
totalrow = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
For currentrow = 2 To totalrow
If Trim(txtLineNumber) = Trim(Cells(currentrow, 2)) Then
txtInvoiceNumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 1)
txtInvoiceDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 3)
cmbCustomerName.Text = Cells(currentrow, 4)
txtDestinationC.Text = Cells(currentrow, 5)
txtDestinationCnty.Text = Cells(currentrow, 6)
txtLine.Text = Cells(currentrow, 7)
cmbBrand.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8)
cmbType.Text = Cells(currentrow, 9)
cmbProduct.Text = Cells(currentrow, 10)
cmbPackaging.Text = Cells(currentrow, 11)
txtCartons.Text = Cells(currentrow, 12)
txtQuantity.Text = Cells(currentrow, 13)
cmbCurrency.Text = Cells(currentrow, 14)
txtUnitPrice.Text = Cells(currentrow, 15)
txtDocumentation.Text = Cells(currentrow, 16)
txtAdditionalF.Text = Cells(currentrow, 17)
txtTransport.Text = Cells(currentrow, 18)
cmbStatus.Text = Cells(currentrow, 19)
txtPdDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 20)
txtCustomerRef.Text = Cells(currentrow, 21)
txtLoadDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 22)
txtASMnumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 23)
cmbWHS.Text = Cells(currentrow, 24)
txtCompleteDate.Text = Cells(currentrow, 25)
txtAccPacNumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 26)
cmbZeroInvReason.Text = Cells(currentrow, 27)
cmbRep.Text = Cells(currentrow, 28)
txtDriver.Text = Cells(currentrow, 29)
txtContactD.Text = Cells(currentrow, 30)
txtContainer.Text = Cells(currentrow, 31)
txtTruckNo.Text = Cells(currentrow, 32)
txtTrailerNo.Text = Cells(currentrow, 33)
txtTransporter.Text = Cells(currentrow, 34)
cmbTransportMode.Text = Cells(currentrow, 35)
txtPOnumber.Text = Cells(currentrow, 36)
cmbCancelR.Text = Cells(currentrow, 37)
txtCrRef.Text = Cells(currentrow, 38)
End If
Next currentrow
End Sub
```

Comment: I have looked into this some more and the error is at the one line of code for some reason. If this cell is blank then I get the error code, if it has something filled in then it works. In the,

     Private Sub cmdFind_Click()
     .....
     cmbBrand.Text = Cells(currentrow, 8)

Comment: If you're getting an error then it's best to mention exactly what the error is and when it occurs.  Would also help to show the rest of your code (ie. complete the 3 subs)

Comment: Hi, Thanks Tim.  The rest of the code and the error amended to the original message

Comment: There is only an error if that specific cell is blank for some reason. It does not mind the rest being blank.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742705/vba-combobox-style